# Successfully replaced \nvotes with ' ' from data but can't perform twice to remove \nvote

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, python-requests

**Problem Introduction**
Language version: Python 3.8
Operating system: Windows 10
Other relevant software: Jupyter notebook and requests-html

I am experimenting with cleaning up some parsed html from a stack overflow [tutorial](https://youtu.be/BFAQCDr6Qvc?t=1853). I was successfully able to replace '3\nvotes' with '3'. However, for posts with 1 vote it still results with '1/nvote'. I tried to replace

```
def clean_scraped_data(text, keyname=None):
    if keyname == 'votes':
        return text.replace('\nvotes', '')
        if '\nvote'in text:
            return text.replace('\nvote', '')
    if keyname == 'summary':
        return text.replace('\nvotes', '')
    return text
```

Other things I have already tried:

```
def clean_scraped_data(text, keyname=None):
    if keyname == 'votes':
        return text.replace('\nvotes', '')
        if text == '1\nvote':
            return text.replace('\nvote', '')
    if keyname == 'summary':
        return text.replace('\nvotes', '')
    return text
```

Intended outcome is '1 vote'
Actual outcome:

```
1\nvote
```

I expected 1 vote but received 1/nvote

**I truly think that I am doing this correctly and do not know of my error or any other versions to attempt. Any advice?**

Comment: It seems you are `return`ing too early. The second `if` is never reached.

Comment: Yes, on the third line you might want to try: `text = text.replace('\nvotes', '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing some combinations of `vote` / `votes` / `\nvotes` you could use regular expressions deleting all non-numeric characters from text:

```
import re

def clean_scraped_data(text, keyname=None):
    if keyname == 'votes' or keyname == 'summary':
        return re.sub("[^0-9]", "", text)
    return text
```